# Why the following query return all the documents, instead of only those who pass the conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
_id: ObjectId('631b875491b16c38eecfa4e9')
brandName: "Nick"
categories: Array
   0: ObjectId('62f3eaff3ded19dcce71081e')
   1: ObjectId('62f3eb283ded19dcce710824')
products: Array
   0: Object
      productName: "Vans Shoes dsds Old Skool"
      description: "amazing Shoes."
      categoryId: ObjectId('62f3eaff3ded19dcce71081e')
      price: 240
      _id: ObjectId(631b875491b16c38eecfa4ec)
   1: Object
   2: Object
   3: Object
__v: 0
```

My goal is to return only the documents greater or equal to the minPrice.
But unfortunately, all the documents are returned, even the ones with even more minimum prices.

```
  const products = await Brand.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: ObjectId(brandId)
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        products: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$products",
            as: "product",
            cond: { $gte: ["$$product.price", +!!minPrice] },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

So, what's wrong?

Comment: `!!minPrice`, no matter what `minPrice` actually is, will result in either `false` or `true`.  When compared as numbers, those boolean values will be treated as 0 or 1.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but where does the value of `minPrice` come from? Logically, shouldn't every product have a price that is 'greater than or equal to the minimum price of all of the products'? I guess in this context that value comes from somewhere else and represents the (arbitrary) minimum price that you are searching against?